# When should my model belong to another one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm unsure if I can accomplish what I want with my associations.

This is the scenario I want in my application:

A user will select a Store. Then inside of that Store a user selects a product and then can add a new price to that product.

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stores
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business
  has_many :prices
end 

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prices, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :products, :through => :prices
end

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :store
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prices
  has_many :users, :through => :prices
end
```

I'm not sure if this is correct since products don't belong to a store (`integer store_id` in table).

What do I need to do to make this scenario work out? Is this the right design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good and correct design for what you are trying to do.

If a product belonged to a store, then a product could only be at one store.  Since store may have many products and products may be sold at many stores, you need another table referencing both the product and store.

Comment: Yes. The schema looks fine and the only thing I thing is missed is the Store - Product association through :prices, but I am not sure if you will need that one in the app.